# Android Factory Reset Programmatically

Tags: android

I tried to perform a factory reset in Android using the RecoverySystem class, but I get permission errors, which I can not overwrite because they are system permissions. I want to know if there is another way to perform a factory reset?

Comment: Manually? Why would an app *ever* need permission to perform a factory reset?

Comment: This sounds really dodgy. If a user wants a factory reset, they can do it themselves. Those permissions are there for a very good reason.

Comment: Not to mention, if your app did this, it too would be gone after the factory reset anyway...

Comment: As a user, I've been longing for an app that was a one-click reset. This way I could reset my phone remotely in case it gets stolen, by configuring tasker to run this app under the right conditions.

Comment: Permissions are meant to be overridden. *That* is what they are there for. Function entails permissions.

Answer (score 13):

Third party applications most DEFINITELY can do this.

On 2.2+ devices (including latest 4.x) you would have to use the DevicePolicyManager and include permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml. For older devices you can use foreign context loader as described in other answer.

```
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;

  DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
  ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;
```

On Create determine there Android version and get handle on objects

```
    currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        //2.2+
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, WipeDataReceiver.class);
    }
```

The WipeDataReceiver class was a class to implement DeviceAdminReceiver, but did not have any overrides or code updates.

```
    public static class WipeDataReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    }
```

On Resume, initially the will have to confirm Factory Reset. when the Activity returns result it will perform wipeData. If it's Froyo or less, you can jump the stock factory reset activity.

```
if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
    // 2.2+
    if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdmin);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Process will remove user installed applications, settings, wallpaper and sound settings. Are you sure you want to wipe device?");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
    } else {
        // device administrator, can do security operations
        mDPM.wipeData(0);
    }

} else {
    // 2.1
    try {
        Context foreignContext = this.createPackageContext("com.android.settings", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        Class<?> yourClass = foreignContext.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.android.settings.MasterClear");
        Intent i = new Intent(foreignContext, yourClass);
        this.startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: What does "WipeDataReceiver" refer to?

Comment: What is `REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN`?

Comment: What is REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN?

Comment: Are you serious? REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN is just int constant that you initialize any number to differ it from other result requests.. You can write any number to it.. but different from other request codes if you have any..

Comment: WipeDataReceiver is just custom class name that you create.. You can name it differently.. But if you dont know these.. You shouldt work with DeviceAdminPolicy becuase it is advanced level coding.

Answer (score 7):

you have to use DeviceAdministration (API 2.2 or above)

DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
mDPM.wipeData(0);

See:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 3):

This works on a many different devices I have tried. (more than 20)

```
Context foreignContext = createPackageContext("com.android.settings", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
Class<?> yourClass = foreignContext.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.android.settings.MasterClear");

Intent intent = new Intent(foreignContext, yourClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This should no longer work as of around Android 3.0. Use the device admin APIs to request a device wipe.

Answer (score 3):

After Android 8.0, you can send am broadcast to trigger the factory reset process if you can get root permission:

```
am broadcast -p "android" --receiver-foreground -a android.intent.action.FACTORY_RESET
```

Comment: This broadcast do not execute anything

Answer (score 1):

@TapanHP, You can use any ID just to handle the activity result callback.

int REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN =1234;

Answer (score 1):

It helps me

```
 private void resetEverything() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_FACTORY_RESET);
    intent.setPackage("android");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REASON, "MasterClearConfirm");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_WIPE_ESIMS, shouldResetEsim());
    requireActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private boolean shouldResetEsim() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            requireContext());
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(
            requireContext().getString(R.string.reset_esim), false);
}
```

create **preference_keys.xml** in **/values**

```
<resources>
<string name="reset_esim" translatable="false">reset_esim</string>
```

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_FACTORY_RESET` this does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you send the user to the proper settings activity and let them do it themselves.

See [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/calling-system-settings-android-app-gps-example) and use settings activity `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_PRIVACY_SETTINGS`