# How to reset android by program?

Tags: android, reset

How to reset android phone to original status by program?

or Can we use adb to trigger sth?

Many thanks for replying~

Comment: Susantjs you are not describing your problem very good. Why do you want to reset an Android phone? What exactly do you mean with original status?

Comment: take a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798788/android-factory-reset-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798788/android-factory-reset-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember that on API8 (2.2) or later, through the DeviceAdmin API, you can perform a factory reset.
But this is extremely dangerous to the users, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Huang~!! You are right~~ We can reset it by the method wipeData(), according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html You can use the DevicePolicyManager method wipeData() to reset the device to factory settings. This is useful if the device is lost or stolen.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from through the [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), you cannot simply invoke a call and completely factory reset a device, that I'm aware of.

There happens to be a `android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR` permission, but in order for the system to actually grant you that, your app will need to have 'signature' or 'signatureOrSystem' permissions, according to a [Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3af09c76f3ba8d96/d314c4adaaa217c4?show_docid=d314c4adaaa217c4&pli=1). The only way to get one of those is to sign the app against the same certificate as the system, which basically means you either have to work for a device manufacturer or compile and sign your own firmware.

Comment: Or be root and install the application as system!