# Android : Programmatically Factory Reset?

Tags: android, adb

I am having full access to Android system. I have all the super user permission to do all the things from any of my application. I just want to implement one functionality in which I need to reset the device without redirecting user to PRIVACY_SETTINGS. If anyone knows how to achieve that please share with me.

Its kind of urgent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use device admin. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html It allows you to wipe all the data. There's a good sample in API demos.

Answer (score -1):

Programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885303/1257591
It shows two ways, one is the implementation mentioned by Mighter and an approach for older devices (android version < 2.2)

ADB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829600/1257591
Contains adb commands and an example. Judging from the tag of your question this might be the answer you are looking for.