# Code for programatically factory reset android device

Tags: java, android

I need help, I want to factory reset my device using code in an application

Comment: sorry, but this is not the place to request for codes. At least you should show some effort.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798788/android-factory-reset-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

you can not do it directly. What you can do is launch an `Intent` to open the settings where the option is located

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the `DevicePolicyManager` and include `permissions` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`
refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798788/android-factory-reset-programmatically)....