# Open "Backup and reset" in Settings Programmatically

Tags: android

I want to open **Backup and reset** in Android Setting. For example If you want to open **Wi-Fi** in Android settings you can use this code :

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

But I found nothing that could help me to open **Backup and reset**. Has anyone seen any implementations of how to do that?

Comment: May this help you in some way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798788/android-factory-reset-programmatically

Comment: thanks a lot @Apurva but i do not want to do reset programmatically. I just want to open back up and reset. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is old, But you can open Backup and Reset with this intent

```
Intent backupIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_PRIVACY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(backupIntent);
```

Comment: It works up to Android 9. With version 10 Privacy Settings activity will be opened but there is no backup settings

Answer (score 2):

As for the latest Android Q Beta release, the accepted answer should not be valid anymore.

The Backup feature has now been moved to the System settings group (same as date/hour settings and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Just Looking at [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) Reference docs, there is NO Direct intent to OPEN the Backup and Reset Settings directly using Intent mechanism!

Comment: Yea, I've seen that class before. I just hope that maybe there is a way to do that. ;)

Comment: I've reached my daily vote limit. I'll upvote your answer tomorrow but still hope to find a better answer ;)

Comment: If it is NOT documented in developer.android.com, I guess it is fair to assume it is not there!! Otherwise, Google must have documented it as they did for all other activities in Settings API

Comment: Yes!! I am  just out of Curious, what exactly are you trying to achieve?          if you are trying to RESET Programatically, then there is a way using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to open backup and restore programmatically. Tested on S8 and Essential PH-1

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$PrivacySettingsActivity"));
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```